# Locally built clang is missing libc++ include paths on Mac

Tags: xcode, macos, clang++

I'm building clang from source against a locally built llvm, but the resulting clang++ executable cannot find the libc++ include paths. Specifically, the steps I'm taking are

1. ```
   $ git clone https://github.com/llvm-mirror/llvm && cd llvm && git checkout <specific revision>
   $ mkdir build && cd build && \
       cmake .. && \
       make -j 4 && \
       make install DESTDIR=../install
   ```
2. ```
   $ git clone https://github.com/llvm-mirror/clang && cd clang && git checkout <specific revision>
   $ mkdir build && cd build && \
       cmake -DLLVM_CONFIG=../path/to/locally-built/llvm-config \
             -DCLANG_DEFAULT_CXX_STDLIB=libc++ 
             .. && \
       make -j 4
   ```

However, my locally built clang++ can't find the local libc++ include paths:

```
$ cat foo.cpp
#include <iostream>
$ ./clang++ -v foo.cpp # my locally built clanfg
...
clang -cc1 version 9.0.0 based upon LLVM 9.0.0svn default target x86_64-apple-darwin18.6.0
...
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 /Users/ccotter/git/clang/build/lib/clang/9.0.0/include
 /System/Library/Frameworks (framework directory)
 /Library/Frameworks (framework directory)
End of search list.
foo.cpp:1:10: fatal error: 'iostream' file not found
#include <iostream>
         ^~~~~~~~~~
$ clang++ -v foo.cpp # xcode's clang
...
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1
 /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/11.0.0/include
 /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include
 /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include
 /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks (framework directory)
End of search list.
```

I'm using the xcode 11 provided toolchain on Mac OS Mojave to build llvm+clang from source here. How can I get my locally built clang++ to see the xcode provided libc++ headers? Is it a step I need to specify at cmake configure time?